# Xcode fails to build working flutter project

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, cocoapods

I'm working on a Flutter project with a team. I've mostly been working on Windows, where I test on Android and everything runs smoothly. I got myself a Mac specifically to be able to test on iPhone, but my Xcode keeps failing to build the iOS app.

One of my teammates is working on Mac and managing to build and test perfectly fine, so I asked him to merge to master on git, and I pulled from master. I figured since the only ios related thing on gitignore is **/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id, everything on the build should be good to go. Even so, I pulled his version, and it won't run as is on my laptop. So I figure it's probably some local xcode setting or another problem with my mac.

If I try resetting my Xcode settings using `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode` on the terminal, the following problem pops up:

[image: Sandbox not in sync error]

My cocoapods is up to date at version 1.15.0. So that's not the issue. As established before, the pods aren't in git ignore, so they shouldn't be a problem. That said, I try running pod install in the ios folder anyway. Here's the result:

[image: pod install log]

Cool, no errors, right? So I try running build again:

[image: unhandled exception]

So I get this unhandled exception. I go to the classic `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` in visual studio. And the logs say 'Xcode build done'. But immediately after, there's 'Failed to build iOS app'.

[image: Failed to build iOS app]

And at this point, I assumed VS Code simply wasn't connecting with the simulator, so I headed over to Xcode to try to build. And here's what happens.

[image: Plugin registrant error]

So basically, it becomes a rabbit hole of problems. Googling and fixing each one takes me right back to the unhandled exception.

Some other stuff I've tried to fix the issue so far
-Making sure Runner iOS number target matches Podlock iOS number target
-Removing the ios build folder completely and then generating it again
-Simply using `flutter build ios`
-Making sure I'm using the runner.xcworkspace file

Nothing's worked so far, and I know for a fact the project is fine. Has anyone had any similar issues? Does anybody have any idea what could be going wrong?

Thank you all.

Comment: do run commands like 
flutter clean, flutter pub get , cd ios , pod install and then open in xcode.
before all commands clear derived data too.